# Python, why does this print None, and what is the fix?

Tags: python

When I run the following code, it prints the word 'None'. It should print the amount entered by the user. Why does it do this, and how do it fix it?

```
def amount(thing):
    amnt = int(input('How many ' + thing + ' would you like?'))

bolts_amount = amount('bolts')
print(bolts_amount)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` a value from the function, otherwise it defaults to returning `None`

```
def amount(thing):
    amnt = int(input('How many ' + thing + ' would you like?'))
    return amnt

bolts_amount = amount('bolts')
print(bolts_amount)
```

Doing `amnt = int(input('How many ' + thing + ' would you like?'))` locally inside your function does not effect your result outside of the function. You need to `return` this value, so that when you call your function `amount()`, it will give you a value to assign to a variable, `bolts_amount`